# How to obtain information gain from a scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I see that DecisionTreeClassifier accepts criterion='entropy', which means that it must be using information gain as a criterion for splitting the decision tree. 
What I need is the information gain for each feature at the root level, when it is about to split the root node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only access the information gain (or gini impurity) for a feature that has been used as a split node. The attribute `DecisionTreeClassifier.tree_.best_error[i]` holds the entropy of the i-th node splitting on feature `DecisionTreeClassifier.tree_.feature[i]`. If you want the entropy of all examples that reach the i-th node look at `DecisionTreeClassifier.tree_.init_error[i]`.

For more information see the documentation here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/dacfd8bd5d943cb899ed8cd423aaf11b4f27c186/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L64

If you want to access the entropy for each feature (at a certain split node) - you need to modify the function `find_best_split` https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L713

Comment: I didn't realize there was documentation on the github.  Thanks.